# Creating product in Magento 2 programmatically

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to create products programmatically in Magento 2, everything is working except for some of them which I'm getting:

> There has been an error processing your request
> URL key for specified store already exists.

This is my code so far:

```
$sku = $row[0];
            $name = $row[1];
            $getSku = $product->getIdBySku($sku);

            if($getSku) {
                echo 'Product with SKU '.$sku.' already exists';  

            } else {

                    $product->setSku($sku); // Set your sku here
                    $product->setName($name); // Name of Product
                    $product->setAttributeSetId(4); // Attribute set id
                    $product->setStatus(1); // Status on product enabled/ disabled 1/0
                    $product->setWeight(10); // weight of product
                    $product->setStoreId(1);
                    $product->setVisibility(4); // visibilty of product (catalog / search / catalog, search / Not visible individually)
                    $product->setTaxClassId(0); // Tax class id
                    $product->setTypeId('simple'); // type of product (simple/virtual/downloadable/configurable)
                    $product->setPrice(100); // price of product
                    $product->setStockData(
                                            array(
                                                'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                                                'manage_stock' => 1,
                                                'is_in_stock' => 1,
                                                'qty' => 999999999
                                            )
                                        );
                    $product->save();



            $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Product with SKU '.$sku.' Added');
            }
```

SKU and product name are coming from a CSV which is already done...so don't worry about that. I'm trying to get this issue solved, looks like it tries to create a product url with same name? Maybe there are 2 products with same name, it is possible to magento generate custom url, for example, name-1 name-2 instead of using the same, I think that's the issue...

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it, in case someone else have the same issue, its because of naming, you can do something like this:

```
$product->setName($name . " - " . $sku);
```

And the url will be different

Comment: is there no option for setUrlKey ?